# Getting values into an array via scanf

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, scanf

```
.data
arr: .long 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
arr_size: .long 10
in: .string "%d"

.text
.global main
main:

#scanf
movl $0, %ecx # index i
scanloop:
  cmpl arr_size, %ecx 
  je endscan # if ecx == 10 -> break
  leal arr(, %ecx, 4), %eax # load the address of arr[i] into eax
  pushl (%eax) # push the value that is being pointed at onto the stack
  pushl $in
  call scanf
  addl $8, %esp 
  incl %ecx
  jmp scanloop
#endscanf

endscan:
#...
```

I don't know how to "scanf" values into an array. I thought it'd work if I calculate the address of each index, push the value that the address points to onto the stack and call scanf. But I get a memory access error.

So, is there a way to do it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons I cannot tell it works if I use %edi instead of %ecx as my index.

I still don't know how to use a debugger, so I printed out my index in every iteration to see what's wrong. The thing was that %ecx never got beyond 1, which made the procedure stuck in an infinite loop.

With %edi, however, incrementation works perfectly fine.

PS: Out of curiosity I've tried other registers as well, namely %esi and %ebx. It also works for them. If I ever find out the reasons for this, I'll refer back to this post.

Edit: Ok, the mistake was a silly one. I didn't obey to the calling conventions.

So `scanf`, like `printf`, apparently changes register values. By convention, `%eax`, `%ecx` and `%edx` are *caller-save*, whereas `%ebx`, `%edi` and `%esi` are *callee-save*.
Because I, as the caller, didn't save `%ecx` prior to the call to `scanf`, I got an unwanted value in `%ecx`.
It worked for `%edi`, `%esi` and `%ebx` because these are callee-save, hence guaranteed to be not changed by the called function. So if I had tried `%eax` or `%edx` instead, it most likely wouldn't have worked either.

And yes, it works perfectly fine if I push `%ecx` on the stack before calling scanf.

Edit2:
Oh, and solved the issue with the access problem by making myself a global variable in which I scan a number, and move that number into the desired index:

```
.data
num: .long 0
#...
scanloop:
  cmpl arr_size, %ecx 
  je endscan # if ecx == 10 -> break

  pushl %ecx #caller-save
  pushl $num
  pushl $in
  call scanf
  addl $8, %esp
  popl %ecx #restore
  movl num, %eax #in order to avoid two memory arguments to movl

  leal arr(, %ecx, 4), %edx #calculate address of index
  movl %eax, (%edx) #store num in that index

  incl %ecx
  jmp scanloop
#endscanf
#...
```

Comment: EDI is call-preserved, unlike EAX, ECX, and EDX, in the i386 System V calling convention.  EAX is also scanf's return value, so of course it wouldn't work.  Just use a call-preserved register instead of doing push/pop of ECX inside the loop; scanf is already pushing/popping those regs for you if it uses them.